# Can't test my Android apps on my LG MS395

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-debug

I've allowed USB debugging on my phone and connect it through my USB port. But it doesn't show up in "Choose a Running Device" (I'm using Android Studio 1.2.2).

I thought I'd have to update the USB driver for it or something, but when I look up online for an LG MS395 USB driver, I come up with nothing.

So, as of now, I'm stumped and am wondering if this 4G phone is actually incapable of testing Android apps (which seems asinine to me honestly). Hopefully there's an extremely simple solution you guys can point me toward.

The phone is an LG Optimus F60 with a model # of LGMS395.

Comment: better you can use some third-party application like  MoboRobo to connect your phone,But some times you will face a issue like adb not responding, restart the adb will fix the issue.

Comment: Now I get a "ADB not responding. If you'd like to retry, then please manually kill "adb.exe" and click 'Restart'" error

Problem is, I don't see any adb.exe in task manager, ever. So, I can't kill it.

I'm using a windows computer as well

Comment: Restart the computer solve the issue, but there is a chance for repeat..